# C++ Visual Studios 2015: #ifdef WIN32 not executing properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on a large inherited C++ project and am trying to build it for the first time in VS 2015.I have all the build files, but my build is failing in visual studios because the conditional

```
#ifdef WIN32
 .....
#else error
```

I am trying to run on windows, but the program always is falling back to the else statements logic.

I have everything possible installed for C++ in visual studios. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some Windows headers define `WIN32`. The compiler defines `_WIN32`.

Answer (score 7):

VS 2015 defines `_WIN32`, not `WIN32`. See [this list of predefined macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).